# Modules disappeared when I choose switchBootJdk to open jdk10.0.2 in intellij-idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Recently I want to use IDEA-Checkstyle to check proplems in my project.
But defalut jdk for idea running is jdk1.8 which seems not supported by checkstyle, So that I have to switch boot jdk to jdk-10.0.2, but after i did that, modules disappeared.

Environment:
jdk:jdk-10.0.2
idea:Intellij-idea 2018.3.2

Comment: The github page says that it requires JDK8: https://github.com/jshiell/checkstyle-idea. What's the initial problem you had? Why it didn't work with JDK8?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
In my project we need to upgrade jdk from jdk8 to jdk10,
but after i set java compiler to 10, when i run checkstyle again, error as below happened.


Unexpected Exception Caught
The scan failed due to an exception: An error occurred while scanning a file.
Root cause:  ResourceNotFoundException has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

So, i choose swithBootJdk  to jdk10, Unfortunately, the problem as title occurred.